# Is witr prayer obligatory?

Tags: salat, wajib, witr

I heard somewhere that witr is not Obligatory.

It is a part of Qayam ul Layl.

Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Witr Prayer is **Wajib** according to **Hanafi school of thought**. In a renowned Fiqh Hanafi Book **Hidayah** it is said like this:

> **الوتر واجب عند أبي حنيفة رحمه الله**

**Translation:**

> **Witr is Obligatory, According to Abu Hanifa (R.A)**
>
> Reference: Hidaya, Book 1, Page 66, Published: Beirut.

According to **Imam Shafa'i, Imam Malik and Imam Ahmad**, Witr Prayer is **Sunnat e Muakkadah (سنة مؤكدة)** which is some what similar to Wajib.

In the Shafa'i School of Thought Book, **Rauztu Talibeen,** it is stated:

> **الْوَتْرُ سُنَّةٌ. وَيَحْصُلُ بِرَكْعَةٍ، وَبِثَلَاثٍ، وَبِخَمْسٍ، وَبِسَبْعٍ، وَبِتِسْعٍ، وَبِإِحْدَى عَشْرَةَ**

**Translation**

> **Witr is Sunnah, and is offered in Single Rak'at or Three or Five, or Seven or Nine or Eleven Rak'ats.**
>
> Reference: Rauzatu Talibeen, Book 1, Page 328, Published: Beirut.

In a Maliki Fiqh Book, it goes like this:

> **وَهُوَ عِنْدَنَا سُنَّةٌ مُؤَكَّدَةٌ**

**Translation:**

> **and this (Witr) is, according to us, Sunnah Muakkadah.**

**Then it says.**

> **وَهُوَ الْفَرْدُ وَاحِدًا**

**Translation:**

> **And it is Only one Rak'at.**
>
> Reference: Az Zakheerah Lil Qarafi, Book 2, Page 392, Published: Beirut.

And in a Hanbali Fiqh Book **Al Kaafi** states about Witr like this:

> **الوتر. وهو سنة مؤكدة، لمداومة النبي صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ في حضره وسفره**

**Translation:**

> **Witr, and it is Sunnah Muakkadah, because of Prophet's (ﷺ) offering it regularly, while at home and in Journey.**
>   Reference: Al Kaafi, Book 1, Page 265, Published: Beirut.

Comment: allah command us to follow prophet muhammed(sal) not based on our own desire to follow someone. so, if you follow someone you will be questioned during Qiyama and your leader will leave you on that time except mohammed (sal) .

Comment: there is authentic hadith from buhari 46, then you why seek something else?

Comment: Then what about Bukhari 997 and 998????

Comment: nothing in that . its just about vitr. prohet said make it witr as last prayer of the night. beyond witr you shouldn't do anything else til fajr. you are not allowed to do even nafil. this is rules to restrict people

Comment: do you believe mihraj ? how much salah does allah obligate to us during mihraj? dont you think if witr is obligatory it will against mihraj? allah mandatory 5 times prayer . dont include witr in it. allah dont want to give burden to us. if you wish you can pray simply

Comment: Wajib in the hanafi madhab is somewhere between fard and sunnah muakkada in other madhabs. It is not obligatory per se!

Answer (score 1):

There are five [*fard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fard) (obligatory) prayers in Sunni Islam:

> You have to offer perfectly the five compulsory prayers in a day and night (24 hours), unless you want to pray Nawafil.
>   <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 1891](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/1)</sub>

In the Hanafi madhhab, witr (among other prayers) are considered *sunnah muakkadah* ([SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/09/13/details-regarding-witr-confirmed-sunna-and-non-confirmed-sunna-prayers/)), which is defined as:

> It is that Sunnah which [Prophet Muhammad] and the [Companions of the Prophet] had done with continuity or had emphasized it and leaving this Sunnah without a valid reason will lead to committing a sin and this person will be deprived of [Prophet Muhammad's] intercession on the day of [resurrection].
>   <sub>[efiqh.com](http://efiqh.com/2012/what-is-a-sunnat-muakkadah/)</sub>

So witr is considered *wajib* (necessary; essential) by Hanafis.  Consequently, Hanafis may consider [the sunnah muakkadah prayers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salah#The_Five_Daily_Prayers) as virtually obligatory.

See also [What is the difference between fard and wajib?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/852/17163)

Answer (score 0):

According to most scholars, witr is not compulsory, only in the Hanafi school is it close to being fard (but even there it is not exactly fard). That being said, I still think it is good idea to offer at least one rakah of witr after isha (just to be on the safe side). I like how Sharkh Yasir Birjas said there is something wrong with your Iman if you do not offer the night prayer (qiayam al lail aka tahajjud aka witr) on at least some nights (and this is assuming you pray the obligatory five).

Answer (score 0):

There is no prayer is obligatory except `5 times salah` until you wish to do.. here is the proof. and moreover allah command us to follow prophet muhammed(sal) not based on our own desire. so, if you follow someone you will be questioned during Qiyama and your head will leave you on that time.

> Al-Bukhaari (46) and Muslim (110) narrated that Talhah ibn ‘Ubayd-Allaah said: A man came to the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and when he drew close to him he asked him about Islam. The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Five prayers each day and night.” He said: “Do I have to do anything else?” He said: “No, not unless you do it voluntarily.” And the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “And fasting Ramadaan.” He said: “Do I have to do anything else?” He said: “No, not unless you do it voluntarily.” And the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) told him about zakaah. He said: “Do I have to do anything else?” He said: “No, not unless you do it voluntarily.” The man left, saying, “By Allaah, I will not do any more than this or any less.” The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “He will succeed, if he is speaking the truth.”