# Importance of praying witr before fajr

Tags: source-identification

I recently stumbled upon an article on facebook saying

> It is sunnah of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) to pray 2 witr before 2 fard
>   in Fajr.

That ha set in me so strong that I started praying but now I want to find a source and where it is mentioned?

Comment: 2 witr needs clarfiication as witr certainly is an "odd raka'a" prayer. As the word witr وتر means odd.

Comment: @Medi1Saif thank you as I came to know witr is odd number of rakats last Ramadan. Also I read there is a sunnah that before every namaz, it is sunnah to pray 2 rakat sunnah.

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah it is good that your making action on Witr salaat.

According to the school of Imaam Abu Hanifah rahmatullah alayh, Witr salaat is Waajib (Necessary) to be performed falling Salatul ‘Ishaa.

Check this out 
https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/40931

The strictest position that I have read from bodies of ‘Ulamaa such as the Mujlisul ‘Ulamaa of Port Elizabeth South Africa is that the Fajr salaat that is performed without Witr, must be repeated with Witr being made qadha.

http://www.themajlis.info/20216/if-one-forgot-to-make-witr-and-realises-only-after-fajr-what-should-be-done

The best time to perform Witr is following Tahajjud.

https://seekersguidance.org/answers/hanafi-fiqh/praying-witr-after-tahajjud-make-ups/

Comment: This strongest position is very weak as witr is certainly not obligatory even in the Hanafi maddhab at the same level of the five obligatory prayers. It is referred to as "wajib" (Hanafi terminology where wajib < fard) not  as "fard" which is equal to obligatory and therefore leaving a fard prayer is sinful.

Comment: To clarify - by “strong” I meant, for lack of a better word, most “extreme”. Not in terms of accuracy, validity or reliability, although it may fulfill all of those qualities as well, depending on the da’leel they possess. Allaah knows best. In sha Allaah you should take your comments up with the body of ‘Ulamaa who I’ve referred to, their contact information is readily available via online search and they respond to inquiries fairly quickly. I lack knowledge of Fiqh to engage in this matter any further. I read their position in one of their newsletters from some time ago.